# What are some good Repository pattern examples for use with Entity Framework 4.0?

Tags: entity-framework, repository-pattern, entity-framework-4

Can anyone refer me to good and complete/semi-complete examples of using EF 4 with the Repository pattern? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally do not use EF but take a look at this project http://www.codeproject.com/KB/linq/ef.aspx